# Adding class to TableSorter filter widget inputs?

Tags: class, input, filter, widget, tablesorter

Does anyone has an idea on how to add unique class to input field of the filter widget.

I got dynamic table with some hidden columns which users can add or remove at their side along with default columns that are shown.

I managed to accomplish with JQuery:

```
$( "#table tr td > input" ).each(function( i ) {
$(this).attr('id', 'column' + i);
$(this).append('<input id=\"column' +i+'\"></input>');
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
$(this).find('input').append(script);
});
```

but, there is a problem. When i add one hidden column or remove one, the column with id column6 becomes column with id of column5 and vice versa.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue ? I need specific ID or class on the filter widget input at all times.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`filter_cssFilter` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-cssfilter) to set a different class name per column on each filter input.

```
$(function(){
  $("table").tablesorter({
    widgets: [ "filter" ],
    widgetOptions: {
      // css class applied to the inputs within the filter row
      // string (applied to all), array (applied to individual)
      filter_cssFilter: [ "filter0", "filter1", "filter2" ] // etc...
    }
  });
});
```

---

update: Maybe including the header text would work better? ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/209/))

CSS (`input.tablesorter-filter` added to increase specificity)

```
input.tablesorter-filter.filter-AlphaNumeric { border-color: red; }
input.tablesorter-filter.filter-Numeric { border-color: green; }
input.tablesorter-filter.filter-Animals { border-color: blue; }
input.tablesorter-filter.filter-Sites { border-color: purple; }
```

Script

```
$(function() {

  var filterArray = [];
  $('thead th').each(function(){
    filterArray.push('filter-' + $(this).text().replace(/\s/g,"-"));
  });

  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
      filter_cssFilter: filterArray
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Half way there :D, this works but, when I add some of the hidden column right before the column that i need the unique ID, so i can target that filter input, added column takes the place of the old column. For Example: I need column 8 to be with unique ID filter8, I am adding a column before that column and now added column is with ID filter8 and the column that i need is with ID column9. Thanks...

Comment: O.K. Maybe I am doing it the wrong way. What i want to achieve is simple. i want to have exact match like when you searching with " (quote) and filter parsed at the same time, so the $ sign to be ignored. Adding the filter-exact and filter-parsed class in the header wont work the same as when searching with " (quote) in the filter input. And i want to achieve this on some of the columns, not all columns. Thanks...

Comment: I've updated my answer. We discussed the `filter-exact` and `filter-parsed` through email, so others might be confused that it was brought up here. Anyway, use the [`filter_defaultFilter` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-defaultfilter) instead.

Comment: Works great, I don't have any words. Thanks, you don't know how much you helped me :D.